# How to setup secure communications using AES-256-GCM?

Tags: encryption

I need to have a way to communicate securely over a local network. There are two computers, computer A and computer B, computer A is the server and B is the client.

B opens a channel to A, at which time A generates a session key, that it can then share with B. This certificate is good for one session.

The channel which joins them can be monitored, so a MITM attack is possible, but for the sake of argument lets say the attackers cannot intercept the session key.

The source code will be readily available for both the server and the host.

This must be able to be implemented using C and OpenSSL. Everything must me local so we cannot use a CA or trusted third party.

I am thinking I should use AES-256-GCM but I am open to other options using OpenSSL.

What would be the best way to assure the communication will be secure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using OpenSSL and you are asking the best way to secure communication? Use TLS. Chances that you can create a secure transport protocol out of nothing are slim.

Comment: I think you're confusing session keys (normally different for each connection) with certificates (normally long-lived on the server). The closest I can think of to what you're asking would be TLS with ECDH_anon cipher suites (AECDH prefix in the OpenSSL name). But would it at least be possible to use a self-signed certificate on the server with [trust-on-first-use policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use) on the clients? You might be able to get better recommendations with a better description of the situation.

Comment: BTW, it sounds depressingly like you're on the road to producing yet another insecure program/device/whatever to join the Internet of pwned things. Please don't. Involve someone who knows something about secure design early, and take them seriously. And I don't just mean picking decent protocols; you also want to avoid things like accidentally executing bits of carefully-malformed data sent to the server. We've enough insecure crap out there now, we don't need any more.

Comment: Assume they are simple devices, such as IOT. You are correct that the key generated by A and shared with B will only be good for the single session, that is what I was thinking. The server will keep track of users and cash balances and the client will allow users to deposit funds and purchase things after they supply a mag stripe card that is unique to each person.

Comment: LOL dont worry, it will never be produced or sold. Just a project to learn about security.

Comment: So what if I just used an AES-GCM symmetric key, sent between A and B securely, after which point they utilize this key to encrypt communications? Assuming the key cannot be intercepted (for sake of argument), why would this alone not be sufficient to prevent eve from decrypting any future intercepted communications? thanks